# Stored procedure temporary table causing timeout error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a temporary table in the stored procedure which is causing the time out for the query as it is doing a complex calculation. I want to drop it after it is used. It was created like

```
DECLARE @SecondTable TABLE
```

Now I cannot drop it using

```
drop @SecondTable
```

in fact I have to use

```
drop #SecondTable
```

Does somebody know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm by no means a SQL guru, but why is the drop even necessary?

If it's a table variable, it will no longer exist once the stored proc exits.

I'm actually surprised that `DROP #SecondTable` doesn't error out on you; since you're dropping a temporary table there; not a table variable.

**EDIT**

So based on your comment, my updates are below:

1.)  If you're using a table variable (`@SecondTable`); then no drop is necessary.  SQL Server will take care of this for you.

2.)  It sounds like your timeout is caused by the calculations using the table, not the dropping of the table itself.  In this case; I'd probably recommend using a temporary table instead of a table variable; since a temporary table will let you add indexes and such to improve performance; while a table variable will not.  If this still isn't sufficient; you might need to increase the timeout duration on the query.

3.)  In SQL; a table variable (`@SecondTable`) and temporary table (`#SecondTable`) are two completely different things.  I'd refer to the MSDN documentation for [Table Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx) and [Temporary Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

Comment: it gets droped after the store proc. however in the store proc itself it is making use of the temporary table many times that caused the time out. My Question stays same that what is the difference between Drop #SecondTable and Drop @SecondTable? I didn't get what tempory variable you are talikng about..